# workday holiday argument doesn't accept array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to pass a vba declared array of dates into the Holidays Argument in excel function WorkDay. From the research so far its possible to pass a Range and TechontheNet suggests it is possible to pass an array of date serial numbers. 
The code below is fine up to the point where the workday function is executed - at which point in bombs out...

Note: EasterDate and HolidayDate are functions that return value "date" format, I've also tried running without these values set, but it makes no difference...

```
Function WorkDayFiveA(DateofSpend As Date) As Boolean
    Dim WDFive As Date, RefDate As Date
    Dim Holidays(9) As Date
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

' load holiday array
    Holidays(0) = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 12, 25)    ' last Christmas
    Holidays(1) = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 12, 26)    ' Last Boxing day
    Holidays(2) = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)          ' News year day
    Holidays(3) = EasterDate(Year(Date), 1)             ' Good Friday
    Holidays(4) = EasterDate(Year(Date), 2)             ' Easter Monday
    Holidays(5) = PublicHolidayDate(Year(Date), 1)      ' May day
    Holidays(6) = PublicHolidayDate(Year(Date), 2)      ' Spring Holidays
    Holidays(7) = PublicHolidayDate(Year(Date), 3)      ' Spring Holidays
    Holidays(8) = DateSerial(Year(Date), 12, 25)        ' next Christmas day
    Holidays(9) = DateSerial(Year(Date), 12, 26)        ' next Boxing

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    WDFive = wf.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), 4, Holidays)

    If Date < WDFive Then
        RefDate = DateSerial(Year(WDFive), Month(WDFive) - 1, 1)
    Else
        RefDate = DateSerial(Year(WDFive), Month(WDFive), 1)
    End If

    If DateofSpend < RefDate Then
        WorkDayFiveA = True
    Else
        WorkDayFiveA = False
    End If
End Function
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Can you add the error message and tell us which line is responsible?

Comment: "*at which point in bombs out*" clearly describes what's happening here … NOT.

Comment: Eliminating the `EasterDate` and `PublicHolidayDate` entries and running it here enabled the function to run to completion.  The problem is not what you think.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to provide relevant data.

Comment: After filling your array `Holiday` run `Dim i As Long: For i = LBound(Holidays) To UBound(Holidays): Debug.Print "Holidays(i) = " & Holidays(i): Next i` to check the output in the immediate window. Make sure all dates are valid dates.

Comment: There is no error message. I added a toggle break point at the "set wf = ...." line and then executed line by line and the code executes up to the workday function line and then ends returning #VALUE in the spreadsheet cell where its called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems appear sometimes in **Excel 2016** and always in **Excel 2013** and earlier versions.

A possible solution - the Holdiay array should be consisted of constant serial numbers to work, e.g. declare it as `Long`, not as `Date`:

```
Dim Holidays(9) As Long
Holidays(0) = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 12, 25)    'Last Christmas
Holidays(1) = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 12, 26)    'Last Boxing Day
Holidays(2) = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)          'New Year's Day
```

[The documentation of WorkDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-workday-method-excel):

*Holidays - an optional list of one or more dates to exclude from the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and floating holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that contain the dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that represent the dates.*

---

For me (**Excel 2013** x32) this code works, but does not work if I declare `holidays(3) as Date`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wf              As WorksheetFunction
    Dim holidays(3)     As Long 'As Date does not work
    Dim wdFive          As Date
    
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    holidays(0) = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 12, 25)    ' last Christmas
    holidays(1) = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, 12, 26)    ' Last Boxing day
    holidays(2) = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)          ' News year day

    wdFive = wf.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), 4, holidays)
    Debug.Print wdFive
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to work OK here with Holiday declared as Date.

Comment: I can confirm that the type `Date` for the array items worked for me too. Also you cite only half the documentation, more below it also says "*Important: Dates should be entered by using the DATE function*". So an array of dates should be fine.

Comment: Guy's, Thanks for your all your help. I'm a newby to this forum and self taught in VBA, so apologies for the lack of clarity in the post and possibly unconventional code. Changing the declaration to long works! although is odd, as I tried it as an integer previously without success. Once again many thanks.

Comment: @silvabak - `Integer` will not be successful, because it is up to `32767`. And the current's date is `43124`. So you get an overflow error there.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, can you check the `Edit` and see whether it would really work for you, if you declare Holiday as `Date`?

Comment: @Peh, can you check the `Edit` and see whether it would really work for you, if you declare Holiday as `Date`?

Comment: @Vityata using Windows Excel 2016 x64 works no matter if using `Long` or `Date` which is the same result. If it doesn't work for you this is really odd.

Comment: @Peh - I am with Excel 2013 x32, if I run it as `Date` I get error `1004`.

Comment: @Vityata I have Office365 (32-bit) subscription (VBA 7.1; Excel Version 1712) and your code, copy/pasted and only changing the `Holidays` Data type to `Date`, works fine here.  Must be a difference between 2013 and 2016.  Interesting difference.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - yup, strange difference indeed.

Comment: @Vityata Put like that the integer/long difference makes perfect sense now! To pick-up and possibly further confuse on the sw versions. I'm using Excel 2016 MSA 16.0.4549 64bit & MS VBA 7.1.1056. And after seeing some of the posts above I double checked and switched the declaration back to date - and it fails again. So not sure where this leaves the discussion - but I do have a fix :) So all good! Thanks

Comment: @silvabak Could you possibly upload a copy of  a workbook (with sensitive information removed) demonstrating the problem?  I'd like to try it and see if maybe there is a difference between 64-bit and 32-bit Excel, or something else going on.  If you can, upload to some public file sharing site, and post a link here.

Comment: @RonRosenfield Sure, just recreated the problem in a clean sheet with both versions of the code, supporting functions and an embedded image of my results as a reference. I don't use public file sharing sites so can you suggest one?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create hidden worksheet with a named range "Holidays" on it. Put all of the holiday dates there. (You can use your functions EasterDate and PublicHolidayDate as regular if they are public). In you code instead loading holiday array put:

```
 Set Holidays = Names("Holidays").RefersToRange
```