# Use of NETWORKDAYS function

Tags: excel, vba

I have to find the number of working days between two dates which should exclude weekends and National Holidays.
I am using function NETWORKDAYS in vba, this excludes weekends but I want to exclude Some National Holidays as well.
How to use this function NETWORKDAYS(startDate, endDate, [holidays]) for National holidays. It says it accepts [holidays] as a list. I have all the national holidays in an array. how can I use it with this function via VBA ??
Please find the code snippet.

```
Public Function dataFromInputSheetHolidayDates() As Variant
Dim holidayDates As Integer
Dim holidaydatesArray(20) As Variant
holidayDates = Sheets("InputSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For countDate = 0 To holidayDates - 1
holidaydatesArray(countDate) = Format(Sheets("InputSheet").Cells(countDate + 2, "D").Value, "DD-MMM-YY")
Next countDate
dataFromInputSheetHolidayDates = holidaydatesArray
End Function

holidayList = dataFromInputSheetHolidayDates()

Sheets("Estimation").Range("Z" & taskcounter).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(X" & 
                   taskcounter & ",Y" & taskcounter &","& holidayList & ")"

Sheets("Estimation").Range("AB" & taskcounter).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(X" & 
                  taskcounter & ",AA" & taskcounter &"," & holidayList & ")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these 2 lines in your code:

```
Dim holidayDates As Long
holidaydatesArray(countDate) = Sheets("InputSheet").Cells(countDate + 2, "D")
```

In `VBA` Integer is up to `32767`, which is not quite enough for dates. Furthermore, `holidaydatesArray` should have a numeric value and not some text format.

Pretty much similar problem as this one - [workday holiday argument doesn't accept array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402949/workday-holiday-argument-doesnt-accept-array/48403332#48403332)

---

If you are trying to create a flexible formula through VBA, where the holidays are on different worksheet, try this solution:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim holidayLists    As Range
    Set holidayLists = Worksheets(2).Range("D1:D10")
    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B1, C1," & holidayLists.Parent.Name & "!" _
                                                      & holidayLists.Address & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

There the `holidayLists.Parent.Name & "!" & holidayLists.Address` would refer correctly to the worksheet's name of the holidays.

Comment: Should I put holidayList as a whole like a parameter to that function..it says type mismatch

Comment: @AutoEng - have you declared `holidayList` as `Long`? 
If you want it to work as a flexible formula in Excel, it should be a Range, e.g. `A1:A10` or something similar.

Comment: Actually I have that range in different sheet..now how to use it..I was trying to read it into an array and then pass into this function..

Comment: @AutoEng - I see. See the edit, behind the line of my answer.