VBA Workday Function
I've been trying to implement the Workday Function in VBA. The function works fine when I implement it manually in Excel, however, once I translate it to VBA I run into an error. The cell range B1:B5 contains given holidays as dates. Whenever I try to add the holidays to the workday function, I get the following error: "Unable to get the WorkDay property of the WorksheetFunction class".
Sub WorkdayMacro()

Dim PaymDate As Date
Dim holidays As Range
paths = .Range("paths").Value

PaymDate = .Range("First_Payment_Date").Value
Set holidays = .Range("B1:B5")

Dim row As Long
row = 5

For i = 0 To paths - 1

If Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(PaymDate, i) - 1, 1, holidays) = Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(PaymDate, i) Then
.Range("A" & row).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(PaymDate, i)
Else
.Range("A" & row).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(PaymDate, i), 1, holidays)
End If
Next i

End Sub 


I've tried changing the holidays to a single date or omitting them, then the function works fine, so I'm guessing that my problem has to do with how I store the data. Unfortunately, I cannot find anything online that could help me solve this problem. I would appreciate any hints.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402949/workday-holiday-argument-doesnt-accept-array maybe is what's going on here.

That code wouldn't even run as posted, but have you verified that all the cells in that range contain actual date values, not text or other oddities?

I've seen the thread, however, the solution presented is not applicable to my problem as I don't want to code the holidays directly in VBA. Instead, I want to draw them from a given table in my Excel sheet. I've already tried declaring the variable holidays as long, but I don't know how to declare my variably holidays in that case, since I'm currently using range.

The code does run, however, once I omit the "holidays" part which is why I think something with my variable declaration is wrong. The range the holidays part is referring to consists of a list of formulas used to calculate the given holidays. Might that be the issue? Edit: I've tried recreating it with hard pasted dates, and the code still does not work.

The first date, for instance is given by the formula =DATE(YEAR(FirstDate);1;1), where FirstDate is a variable declared in the NameManager. As mentioned in my edit above, I created a second list only containing the dates as hard-pasted values, yielding the same error as mentioned above.

"The code does run" - no it doesn't though? It will not compile.  You've at least maybe chopped out a With...End With

This code works for me. Dates must be recognised by Excel as dates. My format is dd.mm.yyyy.
Sub WorkdayMacro()

   Dim PaymDate As Date
   Dim holidays As Range
   Dim paths As Long, i As Long
   paths = Range("paths").Value

   PaymDate = Range("First_Payment_Date").Value    ' E1
   Set holidays = Range("B1:B5")

   Dim row As Long
   row = 5

   For i = 0 To paths - 1

      With Application.WorksheetFunction
         If .WorkDay(.EDate(PaymDate, i) - 1, 1, holidays) = .EDate(PaymDate, i) Then
            Range("A" & row + i).Value = .EDate(PaymDate, i)
         Else
            Range("A" & row + i).Value = .WorkDay(.EDate(PaymDate, i), 1, holidays)
         End If
      End With
   Next i

End Sub


